# How to validate fields condition wise using express-validator (version 6.6.1 )

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, backend, express-validator

I have a requirement to validate various fields as per params. so in my node js route if a slide equal to one(in params) than validate name, email, and phone number only. if slide equal to two than validate city and state only. if slide equal to three then validate user address is present or not. I want to do this validation in one route. kindly help if possible. Thanks

Comment: It will be better if you shared a code of what you may have tried, that way the SO users can have a look and advise where you might be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got the solution, if the slide value is zero then validate the address, state, postal_code, etc..same if the slide value is 1 and so on..

```
`router.post("/updateUser",
[
    //first step
    body("slide").not().isEmpty().withMessage('please provide slide number.'),
    body("birthDate").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 0)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('BirthDate is required.'),

    body("address").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 0)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('address is required.'),

    body("state").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 0)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('state is required.'),

    body("postal_code").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 0)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('postal code is required.'),

    //second step
    body("interests").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 1)).isArray({
        min: 1
    }).withMessage('at least one interests is required.'),

    //third step
    body("home").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 2)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('homeOwner is required.'),

    //four step
    body("driveVehicle").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 3)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('driveVehicle is required.'),

    //fifth step
    body("vehicleDetails.model").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 4)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('vehicle model is required.'),

    body("vehicleDetails.mileage").if(body('slide').custom((value, {
        req
    }) => value == 4)).not().isEmpty().withMessage('vehicle mileage required.')
],async function (req, res, next) {`
```